# How to Go to the function after clicking the link with the previous value on Kendo UI Grid?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid List with columns:

```
 columns: [{
                field: "LogID",
                title: "Log ID",
                width: 50
            },
            {
                // here i need to show hyperlink 'Link' and after clicking 
                //  here it should call function $scope.thisfuntion(logID) with
                //   parameter LogID above.
            }],
```

i tried using

```
columns: [{
                field: "LogID",
                title: "Log ID",
                width: 50
            },

{                
                field: "",
                title: "",
                width: 200,
                sortable: false,
template: "<a href='\\#' class='link' ng-click='this.thisFunction(LogID)'>#=Link#</a>",
}],
```

but after using this the list of the grid dosen't shows any  value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
template: "<a href='\\#' class='link' ng-click='this.thisFunction(dataItem.LogID)'>#=dataItem.Link#</a>"
```

OR

`template: "<a href ng-click=thisFunction(dataItem.LogID)>#: 'Link' #</a>"`

In kendo, dataitem is a reserved word that represents the object behind the line.

Comment: The problem is same the kendo grid dosen't shows any value. The Error Says :- ``` ReferenceError: Link is not defined ```

Comment: OK. Try it: #=dataItem.Link#

Comment: ReferenceError: dataitem is not defined ,where shoud we defined it on kendo?

Comment: and {{dataItem.Link}}?

Comment: ``` template: "<a href ng-click=thisFunction(dataItem.LogID)>#: 'Link' #</a>" ``` Using this template it Worked